# How to make real natural photos less-real for games?

Tags: photoshop, vector-graphics

I am a web developer trying to make a 2D game for the first time, I am not good in graphic design so I am using raster natural real photos as graphics for my game like this one:

http://www.cgtextures.com/texview.php?id=23142

But the overall looking of the game is not good because the graphics look very 'real' and unprofessional, how easily can I convert the photos to be more like this:

http://fc06.deviantart.net/fs44/f/2009/076/4/3/VW_DragBus_Destroyer_Carbon_by_M2M_design.jpg

I know you are laughing now as it seems it is not easy to convert a real photo to a such professional polished brilliant vector one, but I need something close, can I use some combinations of Photoshop filters and tricks to accomplish this? can I convert the photos to vector graphics then convert them to raster graphics again and add some effects maybe?

Thanks.

Comment: You must be psychic cause I'm so laughing right now :D

Comment: :) I can see dead people too but they are all coders, I need designers, I need one of those magical designers who do magical things with Photoshop using strange tricks like duplicating the layers and playing with filters, opacity, colour modes.. etc

Comment: Posterization or solarization.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I can think off is to run a filter over the image so that it reduces the detail, this would amount smoothing the image with quite a high value.

If you consider that when tyding up a photo taken with a high ISO value (say 1600 which creates a lot of noise in the image) a value of 50% smoothing would reduce the noise but leave detail intact.

You would be looking to really go overboard on this value say 400% which would reduce the image to one that looks like it's been painted almost.

Comment: Thank you RichGK, what kind of filters I can use in Photoshop CS3 or CS4 as this is not my area of expertise.